# update jakarta.mail 1.6.5 to 2.0.1

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to migrate from JakartaMail 1.6.5 to 2.0.1, and when I'm starting my application I got

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
```

I also try to change:

```java
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

to

```java
import jakarta.mail.MessagingException;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

However, then when I use `JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender` of Spring class like:

```java
 MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
```

It says:

```
Required type:
jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage
Provided:
javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
```

How can I solve this? Does Spring support JakartaMail 2.0.1? because JavaMailSender is in spring-context-support (I use version 5.3.9)

Comment: How are you actually doing the migration? You need all supporting libraries

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that JakartaMail 2.x switched to the new `jakarta.mail` namespace. As a result, libraries built against earlier versions of JakartaMail/JavaMail will not work as they expect the `javax.mail` namespace.

Spring 5 still uses the `javax.mail` namespace and thus cannot be used in combination with JakartaMail 2.x. In fact, recent versions of Spring Framework version 5 are compiled against `com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2`/`javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2` (see [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/c27ec00ae94bb3a2555c7762264ff009fa57ee0c/build.gradle#L243)).

If you want to use Spring 5, you need to use JakartaMail 1.6.7 or earlier. As far as I know, version 1.6.7 and 2.0.1 are identical (or nearly identical), except for the difference in namespace.

Support for the new JakartaMail 2.x and its `jakarta.mail.*` namespace were introduced in Spring 6 (and Spring Boot 3).

Comment: thanks, i still wait spring 6. thanks for the link