# Spring and new Jakarte mail version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am facing a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955884/update-jakarta-mail-1-6-5-to-2-0-1), which is related to the jakarta mail version in Spring boot: I want to create a Spring application, which also makes use of a third party jar. This jar makes use of Jakarta mail 2.0.1.

It all started with the error message related to the package name change in Jakarta mail 2.0.1:

```
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
```

I tried to following:

1. Excluding the old jakarta mail with:

```
   <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

which seems to have no effect.

2. Overriding to the version by adding the following tags to the dependies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

This resulted in another Exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.activation.DataSource`, which seems to be Spring internal, since I do not use this class in my code.

I am using *spring-boot-starter-parent* as a parent and the sole Spring dependency is `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Does anybody found a work around to use two versions of the jakarta libarary until Spring updates to Jakarta mail 2.0.1? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: It won't work. Spirng Boot 3 is required (and Spring 6) for support of JakartaEE.